# Current capacity of a diode

Tags: power-supply, power, current

I want to make a 220v rectifier and I want to draw 0.5 amps from it. I am using in4007 diode in full bridge configuration. The diode has a forward current of 1 amp and a power rating of 3w .My question is can I draw 0.5 A from it ? But if we see the power the diode should burn however it is still within the forward curent limit? Why is it so?

Comment: Check the datasheet for peak current. Simulate it with what I assume capacitor after your rectifier and load. Is your average current within the limit? Is the inrush current within limit?

Comment: Yeah both the inrush and average current are within limit.

Comment: Then you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf), the forward drop is less than a volt at 0.5A, so the power dissipation will be less than 0.5W, but only two will be conducting at once, so only 0.25W each average.

By the way, 3W is a crazy amount of power dissipation for that package, and cannot practically be realized. If that's really in a datasheet, it's under very unrealistic conditions.

Comment: Does this mean that I can safely use these diode sfor 220v rectification  and current draw of 0.5A?

Comment: Yes you can use them.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers.